# Code profiling to improve performance : see CPU cycles inside mscorlib.dll?

Tags: encryption, profiling, bouncycastle

I made a small test benchmark comparing .NET's `System.Security.Cryptography` AES implementation vs BouncyCastle.Org's AES.

Link to GitHub code: https://github.com/sidshetye/BouncyBench

I'm particularly interested in AES-GCM since it's a 'better' crypto algorithm and .NET is missing it. What I noticed was that while the AES implementations are very comparable between .NET an BouncyCastle, the GCM performance is quite poor (see *extra background* below for more). I suspect it's due to many buffer copies or something. To look deeper, I tried profiling the code (VS2012 => `Analyze` menu bar option => `Launch performance wizard`) and noticed that there was a LOT of CPU burn inside mscorlib.dll

[image]

***Question: How can I figure out what's eating most of the CPU in such a case?*** Right now all I know is "some lines/calls in Init() burn 47% of CPU inside mscorlib.ni.dll" - but without knowing what specific lines, I don't know where to (try and) optimize. Any clues?

***Extra background:***

Based on the "*The Galois/Counter Mode of Operation (GCM)*" paper by David A. McGrew, I read "*Multiplication in a binary field can use a variety of time-memory tradeoffs. It can be implemented with no key-dependent memory, in which case it will generally run several times slower than AES. Implementations that are willing to sacrifice modest amounts of memory can easily realize **speeds greater than that of AES**.*"

If you look at the results, the basic AES-CBC engine performances are very comparable. AES-GCM adds the GCM and reuses the AES engine beneath it in CTR mode (faster than CBC). However, GCM also adds multiplication in the GF(2^128) field in addition to the CTR mode, so there could be other areas of slowdown. Anyway, that's why I tried profiling the code.

For the interested, where is my quick test performance benchmark. It's inside a Windows 8 VM and YMMV. The test is configurable but currently it's to simulate crypto overhead in encrypting many cells of a database (=> many but small plaintext input)

```
Creating initial random bytes ...
Benchmark test is : Encrypt=>Decrypt 10 bytes 100 times

Name               time (ms)    plain(bytes) encypted(bytes)   byte overhead

.NET ciphers
AES128                1.5969              10              32      220 %
AES256                1.4131              10              32      220 %
AES128-HMACSHA256     2.5834              10              64      540 %
AES256-HMACSHA256     2.6029              10              64      540 %

BouncyCastle Ciphers
AES128/CBC            1.3691              10              32      220 %
AES256/CBC            1.5798              10              32      220 %
AES128-GCM           26.5225              10              42      320 %
AES256-GCM           26.3741              10              42      320 %

R - Rerun tests
C - Change size(10) and iterations(100)
Q - Quit
```

Comment: Hi Sid, I'm the lead developer of the BC .NET lib, and this sort of benchmarking is very welcome. I cloned your GitHub code, but a class appears to be missing (TestResult.cs). In the meantime, may I suggest you get the latest version of the code from CVS, as there have been some minor improvements to AES speed and some major improvements to GCM mode since 1.7 was released. BC implements several variations of the time-memory tradeoffs discussed in the McGrew paper (see alternate constructor for GcmBlockCipher to configure) if you want to refine your test cases in that respect.

Comment: Hey Peter, GitHub's default .gitignore got me. I've fixed that and also moved to the tip of the CVS repo. Some improvement but in small sizes AES-GCM still lags AES-CBC substantially. https://github.com/sidshetye/BouncyBench has it all right now. Appreciate the interest!

Comment: Sid, did you fix some of the issues? I pulled your bench it seems to be considerably faster than above. When I ran [dottrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) on your bench, almost all the time for GCM in `Decrypt` was `Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes.Gcm.Tables8kGcmMultiplier.Init(Byte[])` and for `Encrypt` it was `Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes.GcmBlockCipher.DoFinal(Byte[], Int32)` Which makes sense why it is slower than CBC for small size byte arrays since it's the extra work that is probably amortized out on larger sizes.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, i just noticed that when I'm dottrace profiling it slows down the others methods of encryption considerably more than AES-GCM, so it evened it out more in the relative time differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather lame move from Microsoft as they obviously broke a feature that worked well before Windows 8, but no longer, as explained in [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/12/10/creating-ngen-pdbs-for-profiling-reports.aspx):
:

> On Windows 8 the profiler uses a different underlying technology than
>   what it does on previous versions of Windows, which is why the
>   behavior is different on Windows 8. With the new technology, the
>   profiler needs the symbol file (PDB) to know what function is
>   currently executing inside NGEN’d images.

(...)

> It is however on our backlog to implement in the next version of Visual Studio.

The post gives directions to generate the PDB files yourself (thanks!).